# "В смысле" в начале предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Интересный вопрос.

"В смысле" в начале предложения выделяется знаками?

Зададим вопрос: В каком смысле?

Ответим, например, так:

В том смысле, что он хороший человек. <== В такой версии предложения понятен знак.

В смысле() он хороший человек. <== Ставится ли знак в этом случае?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Фраза, конечно, разговорная. но если именно так нужно записать, то запятая, конечно, нужна. Ведь сочетание "в смысле" грамматически не  связано с последующими словами: ни от этого слова, ни к нему задать вопрос нельзя.